# Cant retrieve right string from C++ code. Is there a generic type for handling unsigned char* on c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

It seams confusing but I'm gonna try to explain it the best I can!

I'm trying to run a C++ DLL on my C# code.

On this DLL I have a method that should return a 20 characters unsigned char*. Representing 5 "words" of  4 bytes. ( The output of a sha-1 algorithm)

I'm using DLLIMPORT on my C# project like this:

```
    [DllImport("hashLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static private extern string CallReturnString(IntPtr pHashClassObject);
```

This should return the 5 WORDS string.

And this is my C++ method that should give away the string:

```
unsigned char* SHA1::Result(/*unsigned *message_digest_array*/)
{
int i;                                  // Counter
int j = 0;
static int s_chString[5];
static unsigned char s_out[20]; // 4 * 5 + 10 de bob
if (Corrupted)
{
    return false;
}

if (!Computed)
{
    PadMessage();
    Computed = true;
}

unsigned int a = 0;
a = H[0];
s_out[0] = (a >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
a = H[0];
s_out[1] = (a >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
a = H[0];
s_out[2] = (a >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
a = H[0];
s_out[3] = (a >> (8*3)) & 0xff;

a = H[1];
s_out[4] = (a >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
s_out[5] = (a >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
s_out[6] = (a >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
s_out[7] = (a >> (8*3)) & 0xff;

a = H[2];
s_out[8] = (a >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
s_out[9] = (a >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
s_out[10] = (a >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
s_out[11] = (a >> (8*3)) & 0xff;

a = H[3];
s_out[12] = (a >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
s_out[13] = (a >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
s_out[14] = (a >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
s_out[15] = (a >> (8*3)) & 0xff;

a = H[4];
s_out[16] = (a >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
s_out[17] = (a >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
s_out[18] = (a >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
s_out[19] = (a >> (8*3)) & 0xff;
s_out[20] = '\0';



return s_out;
}
```

In this code I try to get all bytes from H and put on a char that will be passed to the C# code.

H declaration is :  `unsigned H[5];`

It almost works, but for some reason some combinations gives me crazy results like a 22 members string on C# and with the values all wrong.

I think it has to do with some different types of varibles on C# and C++. **If I could only get all the bytes from the char* exacly as they were in the the C++ code it would be awesome.**

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks a lot guys!

### EDIT :

The general workflow is:

1. My Windows form app creates a new class from the C++ class : `HashWrapper hash = new HashWrapper();`
2. My windows form app send a seed  to the C++ ( which is a SHA-1 algorithm class ) : `hash.SendInput("abc");`
3. My windows form app asks for the result of the c++ algorithm : `string output = hash.ReturnString();`

Here Im gonna put the methods I called on the list on top:

```
 public HashWrapper()
    {
        // We have to Create an instance of this class through an exported function
        this.m_pNativeObject = CreateSHA1Class();
    }

public void SendInput(string inp )
    {
        CallInput(this.m_pNativeObject, inp, inp.Length);
    }

public string ReturnString()
    {

        string ans = CallReturnString(this.m_pNativeObject);

        return ConvertStringToHex(ans); // Converts to Hex
    }
 public string ConvertStringToHex(string asciiString)
    {
        string hex = "";
        foreach (char c in asciiString)
        {
            int tmp = c;
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
        }
        return hex;
    }
```

Comment: `char* == string`, unless you are pasing a buffer to be filled in, in which case, use `StringBuilder`.  However, you're returning a pointer to a local array, which is a no-no.  That array gets cleaned up when the function returns and all references to it are invalid.

Comment: You are returning a `unsigned char*` which may not have a NUL byte in it and does not have a NUL byte in the 21 position.  I suspect your translation into C# is looking for a null terminated string.  Need to see how you use `SHA1::Result` for further help.

Comment: Just edited so you guys can understand more! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, from a design point of view, passing back a static array from unmanaged code to managed code is not a great idea.  What happens if multiple threads have access to that class (for example)?  You'd be better off passing in an array of bytes (and a length) from managed->unmanaged and have the C++ code fill in the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't Reinvent the Wheel

Is there any reason why you cannot use the class provided by Microsoft? There are some problems with your answer, such as recreating the `memcpy` function which would have allowed you to do your memory copy function in around 6 lines of code, or trying to marshal a data string as a null terminated string. You should just use the SHA1 implementation provided by .NET, unless there is a requirement saying you must make your own.

### How to solve your problem in .NET

The problem you are trying to solve literally takes 3 lines of code in .NET, unless you have a requirement to make your own SHA1 implementation using .NET's makes a lot more sense.

```
public static byte[] HashString(string inputString)
{
    inputData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");
    var sha1 = new SHA1Managed();

    return sha1.ComputeHash(inputData);
}
```

Comment: Hi!

I tried something similar a minute ago it was:

            IntPtr i;
            i = CallReturnString(this.m_pNativeObject);
            byte[] ans = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(i)];
            Marshal.Copy(i, ans, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(i));

which I think is pretty close to you suggestion. But it returned me a 4 elemets Byte array and the elements were the same as before. 

With your code I got a array with 20 elements all 0.

Again with my code first 2 numbers ( on the bytes) should be : 36 and 14. but I'm getting 231 and 13. I getting those numbers since the begining. :-(

Comment: @Roiw - your code only returns 4 bytes because Marshal.SizeOf(i) == 4.  On a 32 bit system an IntPtr is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot simply marshal array from return value. If you need to call it many times, I'd start with a custom marshaller:

```
private class ReturnArrayMarshaller : ICustomMarshaler
{

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
    {
        return new ReturnArrayMarshaller(cookie);
    }

    private readonly int byteCount;

    private ReturnArrayMarshaller(string cookie)
    {
        byteCount = int.Parse(cookie);
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        // release unmanaged return value if needed
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[byteCount];
        Marshal.Copy(pNativeData, data, 0, data.Length);
        return data;
    }

}
```

And use it in signature declaration:

```
[DllImport(@"hashLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(ReturnArrayMarshaller), MarshalCookie = "20")]
public static extern byte[] CallReturnString(IntPtr pHashClassObject);
```

Do not forget to specify `CallingConvention.Cdecl` in `DllImport`, because you're not using `__stdcall` modifier in C++ code.

P.S. I beleive you're using unmanaged library not because of just SHA1 hash, because most of cryptography is available as managed classes.